# theorems and mathematical properties to integrate an equation

Tags: integration

i just want to know how would you integrate the next equation and what are the theorems or properties you use.

$$\frac{d}{dt} (y'(t))^2 = -k\frac{d}{dt}(y(t))^2$$

I am sorry for this silly question but i am a bit confused.

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus.  Let $E(t)=y'(t)^2+k y(t)^2$.  Your equation is $\frac{dE}{dt}(t)=0$, so $E(t)-E(0)=\int_0^t E'(s)ds=0$.  Hence, $E(t)=E(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Just deriving $$\frac{d}{dt} (y'(t))^2 = -k\frac{d}{dt}(y(t))^2 \implies 2 y'(t) y''(t)=-2k  y(t) y'(t)$$ So $$y'(t) \left(y''(t)+k y(t) \right)=0$$ which is satisfied either by $$y'(t)=0 \implies y(t)=C$$ or $$y''(t)+k y(t)=0\implies y(t)= ???$$

Comment: and where did you integrate? i am sorry

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{\mathbb{d}}{\mathbb{d}t}((y')^2+ky ^2)=0
$$

The derivative is zero so the term being differentiated must be a constant, $E$.

$$
(y')^2+ky^2=E
$$

$$
y'=\pm\sqrt{E-ky^2}
$$

I now separate variables
$$
\frac{\mathbb{d}y}{\sqrt{E-ky^2}}=\pm\mathbb{d}t
$$

$$
\frac{\mathbb{d}y}{\sqrt{1-\frac{k}{E}y^2}}=\pm\sqrt{E}\mathbb{d}t
$$

$$
w=\sqrt{\frac{k}{E}}y
$$

$$
\sqrt{\frac{E}{k}}\frac{\mathbb{d}w}{\sqrt{1-w^2}}=\pm\sqrt{E}\mathbb{d}t
$$

$$
\frac{\mathbb{d}w}{\sqrt{1-w^2}}=\pm\sqrt{k}\mathbb{d}t
$$

$$
\arcsin(w(t))-\arcsin(w(0))=\pm\sqrt{k}t
$$

$$
w(t)=\sin(\arcsin(w(0))\pm\sqrt{k}t)
$$

$$
y(t)=\sqrt{\frac{E}{k}}\sin(kt+\varphi)
$$

We can see now that the constant $E$ determines the amplitude of oscillations.